# WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames working, but with errors in the log

Tags: ios8, watchkit

I'm using

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(names, contexts: contexts)
```

to update my interface; depending on the data in my app there's a different number of pages to show, e.g. a weather app with cities. When a new city is added or one is removed, I call `WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(names, contexts: contexts)` to show the according amount of pages on the Apple Watch.

It works as expected, but I get lots of errors in the log:

```
...
myapp WatchKit Extension[7035:217998] *********** ERROR -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:] clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:1B7A0006 not found
myapp WatchKit Extension[7035:217998] *********** ERROR -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:] clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:1B7A0005 not found
myapp WatchKit Extension[7035:217998] *********** ERROR -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:] clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:1B7A0008 not found
...
```

This is how my storyboard is set up:

[image]

`names` in my `reloadRootControllersWithNames` e.g. contains three times the string of `city`, which is also the identifier of the upper ViewController.

As I mentioned, everything works fine, but I don't have a good feeling submitting the app with those many errors in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little bit late here, but the only way I've found to eliminate this error is to push a new Interface Controller, then call reloadRootControllerWithNames from the new controller. It is pretty hacky, but I have yet to find another solution that works every time.